# Installing windows on multiple computers at the same time

Tags: windows, hardware, installation, ibm

i need to install windows on a 150 computers for a bank, i've never done anything like this before, so if anyone can help me find a fast efficient way to do so, they are IBM computers all with the same hardware specifications, brand new

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! What you are asking is either too broad or would lead to extended discussions.  Per the [Help Section](http://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask), your question should be reasonably scoped. **If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.**  The question also leans towards a "shopping question" which is also OT.

Comment: [Windows Deployment Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Deployment_Services). Don't get discouraged, it's a lot to learn if you're starting from zero knowledge.

Comment: Hire someone who has done this before.

Comment: It's trite, but I agree with @DanBig, because there are a lot of gotcha's. It's easy enough to get something that _seems_ to be working, but will ultimately give PCs with subtly wrong images that can cause big problems later.

Comment: @JoelCoel, Exactly what I was thinking. If you haven't done that type of bulk imaging before, 1 problem now becomes 150 problems.

Answer (score 8):

There's a million and one different ways you can do this. You need to find which one works for you, and your environment. As other's have stated, this question is a bit too broad.

I'd start by looking at [Windows Deployment Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772106%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). If you want to go one step further, [Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/systemcenter/bb507744.aspx)

Comment: am sorry i know i didnt give out much information, am not familiar with the bank yet, they want to hire me and am a fresh graduate, so as i said never done something like this before and i realy want to learn and do it, i googled it and some people were saying i can use ghost or something like that to make an image and use it, but i was wondering if i can do it in a way that it installed in several pcs at the same moment that would save much time and effort

Comment: @user182559 Yes, that's the point of WDS, SCCM or any of these solutions.

Comment: Installing over the network/PXE boot?

Comment: @user182559 Pickup a book on [MS Certification 70-415](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-415.aspx), it has intros to everything you're looking for. Might want to consider taking the cert exam if you're any good at this stuff too.

Comment: ok am going to start reading about each suggestion and see if i can make a progressive of learning this in a week, thank you everyone